# Not able to find the point of object destruction in python

Tags: python, destructor

Before you jump into suggestions , let me write a POC code similar to my case:

```
class X:
    _instance=0
    def _new__():
        if cls._instance:
            #instance already instantiated , return the same instance 
            return cls._instance
        cls._instance=initialize_instance()
        return cls._instance
```

Now this is my library . The client code works like:

```
var = X()
# Do some operations on var
.
.
.
#end of program
```

The problem that I am facing is when this client code ends , a function in the library must get executed (for some cleanup purposes) . But I have tried `close()` , `__del__()` and both don't get the control when the client program ends. Ideally I think they should because that is then the instance is destroyed. Is there any other way I can achieve this without adding any code to the client side? I would like to client to make only 1 call to get this handle and let the library deal with everything.

Comment: You code is indented all wrong. You'll need to fix that before we can help you.

Comment: Oops sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: You could try [registering an exit handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html).

Comment: Thanks user23571112 . The solution serves my need.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't removed all references to X, because you still have the cls._instance reference. That's why del isn't getting called.

You can wrap the client object in a context manager, and then call whatever you need to call to cleanup on the exit method:

```
class Wrapper:
    has_been_wrapped = False 
    # Use has_been_wrapped and is_first_instance to determine when
    # the last reference to X is gone.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.has_been_wrapped:
            self.is_first_instance = True
            self.has_been_wrapped = True
        else:
            self.is_first_instance = False
        self.var = X(*args, **kwargs)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.var
    def __exit__(self):
        if is_first_instance:            
            # Do whatever you need to do to cleanup self.var here
```

And then anywhere you would use X, use it like this:

```
with Wrapper() as var:
    # now you have an instance of X that will get 
    # cleaned up when the with statement ends.
```